# Is the codomain defined by us when we define a function?

Tags: functions

For example if I define a function such as

$f(x) = x^2$

then set the domain to be {$x|x\in\mathbb{Z}$}

it follows then, that the range is {$f(x)|f(x)\in\mathbb{Z^+}$}

from my understanding of the codomain, it is defined by us when we create a function, therefore in this case would the codomain of the function be undefined, as we haven't set it or would it be $\mathbb{Z}$ or $\mathbb{Z^+}$

Comment: If you haven't defined the codomain, then you haven't defined the function.

Comment: $\{x \mid x \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ is just the same as $\mathbb{Z}$, of course. $\{f(x) \mid f(x) \in \mathbb{Z}^+\}$ is an unusual notation since $f(x)$ is not a variable.

Comment: See the post [Codomain of a function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/777563/codomain-of-a-function) as well as [Isn't codomain of a function ambiguous?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/582974/isnt-codomain-of-a-function-ambiguous) and [Codomain as part of the definition of a function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3900758/codomain-as-part-of-the-definition-of-a-function)

Comment: @Randall So then the codomain can never be interpreted based on the function definition itself? It must also be defined alongside the function.

Comment: Yes, correct.  The definition of a function $f: A \to B$ includes a reference to $B$ already.

Comment: @aschepler I was taught to write the range as {$y | y\in$ (Whatever set)} so I just wrote that with f(x) instead, is this wrong? If it is what would be the correct way to express the range?

Comment: You could write $\{f(x) \mid x \in A\}$ for the range of $f: A \to B$, but that is not what you've written.

Comment: @Randall What about a transformation for example, if an nxn matrix has a rank such that the rank < n then space is "squished" onto a lower dimension, in this case the codomain of the function would be $R^n$ where n = the rank of the matrix, wouldn't the codomain be defined in this case just based on the function itself, as a transformation is basically just a function.

Comment: @Randall oh okay that makes more sense, and looks much neater.

Comment: A function which maps different matrices of the same size to matrices of different sizes would be unusual, but it could be defined. A simple codomain could be the union of several matrix spaces, $\bigcup_{d=1}^n \mathbb{R}^{(d \times d)}$.

Comment: Thank you all for your help, this makes sense now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we want to be precisely technical, we should always specify the codomain when defining a function. A common way of writing this is

> Define function $f: \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$ by $f(x) = x^2$.

Though in less strict contexts, we sometimes use an implicit codomain, especially when the exact codomain set doesn't matter. If you say "Define function $f$ on $\mathbb{Z}$ by $f(x) = x^2$" without mentioning a codomain, I'd probably assume the codomain is also $\mathbb{Z}$. If it makes sense for the formula, a codomain equal to the domain often makes sense. Or often if you don't specify the codomain, it's because it doesn't actually matter: everything we later say about $f$ is true no matter whether the codomain of $f$ is $\mathbb{Z}^+$ (defined to include $0$!) or $\mathbb{Z}$ or $\mathbb{R}$.